# Invalid regex in Qt yet in regex coach this same regex is valid

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I've got following regex which seems to be a valid regex according to regex coach but qt's regexp.isValid says something else. Could anyone tell me what's the story with this expression:

```
^[^,\.:;\*<>\[\]\+\"\\\/]+\.cpp$
```

Comment: What does `errorString()` report? Are you escaping the backslashes properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qregexp.html Qt/C++ needs double escaping, so try to double each backslash like this:

```
^[^,.:;*<>[\\]+"\\\\/]+\\.cpp$
```

I removed also some of them, because inside a character class they don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

`/` should not be single-escaped. It's a regular character in C++.
`[` nor `*` need regex escaping inside a class.
`.` needs regex escaping, not C++ escaping.

Rules:

- If C++ requires escaping (e.g. "), use a single \
- If regex requires escaping (e.g. ]), use a double \
- If regex and C++ both requires escaping, use a triple \
- When you need a single \ for your regex syntax, C++ requires escaping so you get `\\`
- When escaping \ itself, you need three \ in addition to \ itself, so you get 4 .

So:

`"^[^,\.:;*<>[\\]\+\"\\/]+\\.cpp$"`

Comment: #MSalters thanks very much for yor excellent answer. Would accept it but already accepted other one. Sorry. +1 and big thanx